# NPM - can't install css-sprite on winfows 8.1

Tags: python, css, node.js, npm

I am trying to install css-sprite on windows 8.1 and it's failing.
I have installed:

- Windows 8.1 (x64)
- nodejs 0.12 (x86)
- npm 2.5.1 (x86)
- Python 2.7.9 (x86)
- Visual Studio 2013 express (x86)

I try to install by command

```
npm install css-sprite --msvs_version=2013e
```

And got errors ([log](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/savaa/115ef1e5f6af0db67f00/raw/gistfile1.txt))

After this I try to install using command:

```
npm install css-sprite --msvs_version=2013e
```

And got errors ([log](https://gist.github.com/savaa/115ef1e5f6af0db67f00/raw/gistfile2.txt))

Looks like that problem with gaze submodule. I try to install this module separately, but got errors too.

I am novice with nodejs and npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use NodeJS 0.11 gaze 0.6.4 is not working under node 0.12

https://github.com/shama/gaze/issues/173

Comment: I use a mac and node v0.12 and css-sprite works. But a coworker uses windows and it seems not to work.